# Is that possible to append array in jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Is that possible to append array in jekyll?

like, append `{{ site.tweets }}` to `{{ site.posts }}`?

### so here are the data:

```
- name: "日本語"
  prog_num: 10
  prog: "10%"
  img: ""
  type: "language"
- name: "中文"
  prog_num: 100
  prog: "100%"
  img: ""
  type: "language"
```

---

### `concat` doesn't work:

```
{% assign hl = site.data.skills_human_languages %}
{% assign pl = site.data.skills_programming_languages %}
{% assign fw = site.data.skills_frameworks %}
{% assign dt = site.data.skills_design_tools %}
{% assign all_skills = (hl | concat: pl | concat: fw | concat: dt) %}
```

---

I'm using `jekyll b` command with version of 3.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% assign tweetsAndPosts = site.tweets | concat: site.posts %}
```

Then you can use the `tweetsAndPosts` variable to do whatever you need to do.

Documentation on how concatenation works is available at the [Liquid Templates Reference](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters).

Comment: thx, but it doesn't work.

Comment: concat was not implemented in jekyll (see [Bugreport](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5160). But I think you can use [this](https://gist.github.com/BryanSchuetz/52012affd9318ba59e19a74639a8c16a) solution.

Comment: How to use this file? I'm building a blog on Github Pages.

Comment: Don't use the file but how it works.

Comment: @deveth0 ok I see. thx

Comment: Try piping array contents though `push` [Jekyll cheat-sheat](http://jekyll.tips/jekyll-cheat-sheet/) arrays section covers usage, however, for combining arrays ya may have to get clever with a for loop process for each array to be combined.

Comment: For those who says it doesn't work -- READ YOUR ERROR MESSAGE! `concat` works with two **arrays**, so if you are appending an element, put brackets around it to make it a single-element array.